# How can I make urho3d background become transparent in Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, urhosharp, urho3d

I use Urhosharp to display a 3D model on the Xamarin form, and I want to make the Urhosharp view become transparent so the 3D model can overlay(above) the Xamarin form content.

However, it does not work if I set the background color of UrhoSurface to become transparent, and set the "clear color" of Viewport to become transparent.

So how to make the background of the Urho3d become transparent? So I can display the Xamarin form content below the 3D model.